# Ограничить увеличение ширины при заполнении

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Есть макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении внутрь GridLayout(зелёного поля) некоторые кнопки, его ширина начинает увеличиваться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ограничить увеличение ширины при добавлении внутри GridLayout разных элементов?

Код макета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/resultBar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@color/calculateBar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@color/numbersBar"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:rowCount="1">

                <Button
                    style="@style/numButtons"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:text="1" />

                <Button
                    style="@style/numButtons"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:text="2" />

                <Button
                    style="@style/numButtons"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:text="3" />
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/operationsBar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ну наверно установить ему фиксированную ширину.

Comment: @And Если вы имели виду ( android:layout_width="fill_parent" ), то не помогло

Comment: Я имел ввиду фиксированный размер.

Comment: @And Можете подробно объяснить ?

Comment: android:maxWidth="100dp"